# How to save uiimage in a directory on a given nsurl?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata, nsfilemanager

I have fetched UIImage from photos library in ipad using UIImagePickerController. Now I want to save that image in a directory that is associated with my app and contains already added images. I have also got the url of the  directory.

For example : file://localhost/Users/administrator/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/31816EF9-AE1E-40DF-93C4-C67A82E4B85B/Documents/7884/Images/

How can I save uiimage in the specified directory?

Comment: you want to save the image in your mac or in iphone? That url is for simulator... please clear.

Comment: This url is for simulator but I also want the same functionality on ipad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to save it into your Document Directory.

```
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]; 
[pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help but problem still exists. It is saving in the documents directory but does not save image in the intended sub directory specified in the above url

Comment: first you need to check if any directory is not there then create it, then save.